# Fetching from table to edit record on Modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fetch data into fields from a table to edit record on database

I use code below, but in Chrome Console i have a js error: **$tr is not definited**
In fact seem this line have a problem:  $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

When I open modal i cant get data in fields.

Any help to fix this?

TXS

TABLE

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"> ID </th>
            <th scope="col"> Message</th>
            <th scope="col"> Button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $opportunity_follow_up_id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $opportunity_follow_up_message; ?></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark edit_followup">
                Edit Follow-up</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.edit_followup', function(){ 
        $('#edit_followup').modal('show');
        alert ('working!');

        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        console.log(data);

        $('#update_id').val(data[0]);
        $('#opportunity_follow_up_message').val(data[1]);

    });
```

});

MODAL

```
<div class="modal fade text-left modal-borderless" id="edit_followup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel33" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel33">New Follow-up </h4>
    </div>

    <form action="action/record_opportunities_follow_up.php" method="post" novalidate>

        <input type="hidden" id ="opportunity_follow_up_opportunities_id" name="opportunity_follow_up_opportunities_id" value="<?php echo $opportunities_id; ?>" />

            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Follow-up Message</label>
                    <textarea data-length=250 class="form-control char-textarea" id="opportunity_follow_up_message" name="opportunity_follow_up_message"  rows="3" placeholder="*" required data-validation-required-message="Required"></textarea>
                    <small class="counter-value float-right"><span class="char-count">0</span> / 250 </small>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="update_id" id="update_id">
            <div class="form-group">   
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Next follow-up Date</label>
                    <input type="text" id ="opportunity_follow_up_message" name="opportunity_follow_up_message" value="" placeholder="dd-mm-aaaa" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">        
                <div class="controls">
                    <label>Next follow-up Time</label>
                    <input type="text" id ="opportunity_follow_up_next_time" name="opportunity_follow_up_next_time" value="" placeholder="hh:mm:ss" class="form-control" data-mask="00:00:00">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input bg-primary" name="opportunity_follow_up_completed" id="opportunity_follow_up_completed" value="1">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="opportunity_follow_up_completed">Mark follow-up as complete</label>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="updatedata" value="save" class="btn btn-primary ml-1 block-page">
                <i class="bx bx-check d-block d-sm-none"></i>
                <span class="d-none d-sm-block">UPDATE</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with `let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');` ?

Comment: It seems like you have `use strict` in your file. And it doesn't allow you to declare variables without `var`, `let` or `const`

Comment: Kenny, worked with LET, big thank you for your time!

Comment: I am adding an answer. Please accept it

Comment: sure, please post answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have `use strict` in your file. And it doesn't allow you to declare variables without `var`, `let` or `const`

So declare your variable

Either by `var`, `let` or `const`

In your case you are not changing variable value so `const` is more preferable.

Like

```
const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
```